# Positive and negative curvature de Sitter spacetimes

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, curvature, de-sitter-spacetime

I'm reading Mukhanov's "Physical foundations of cosmology" and in the section on the de Sitter universe, he examines a perfect fluid with pressure $p$ equal to negative of the energy density $\rho$. Then, the so-called "acceleration equation" is given by $$\ddot a-{H_\Lambda}^2 a=0$$ where $a$ is te scale factor and $H_\Lambda= \sqrt{\frac{8\pi G\rho}{3}}$.
The solutions are thus given by exponentials, $$a=c_1 e^ {H_\Lambda t} + c_2 e^{-H_\Lambda t}$$
Plugging the previous equation into the Friedmann equation $(\frac{\dot a}{a})^2+\frac{k}{a^2}= H_\Lambda$ gives a restriction on $c_1$ and $c_2$ in the form of the equation $$4{H_\Lambda}^2c_1c_2=k$$
Then, it says that for non-zero $k$, we can choose the time $t=0$ so that $\lvert c_1\rvert=\lvert c_2\rvert$.
What I understood from this is that if we set $a(0)=c_1+c_2=0$. This means that $c_1=-c_2$ (and also $\lvert c_1\rvert=\lvert c_2\rvert$).

This gives $a=c_1(e^ {H_\Lambda t}-e^ {-H_\Lambda t})$ which is a hyperbolic sine function, regardless of whether the curvature is positive or negative. However, the book says it's only so for negative curvature, and a hyperbolic cosine for positive curvature. I don't understand how that is the case.

Comment: You misunderstand the "choice of time origin" condition. We cannot assume that $a$ ever takes the value zero in general (a big bang is not a necessity). Instead, we can always shift $t \to t - T$ for some constant $T$ chosen to make $c_1$ and $c_2$ equal in magnitude (concretely we take $2H T = \ln|c_1/c_2|$). The relative sign of the two coefficients cannot be changed in this way, and indeed is dictated by the condition $4H^2 c_1 c_2 = k$.

Comment: As you can see from your expression with $k$, clearly having $c_1$ and $c_2$ opposite signs leads to a negative $k$.